# Parse SDK/Wrapper for Cocos2d-X game engine

Tags: sdk, parse-platform, cocos2d-x

I'm developing a mobile game using Cocos2d-X game engine.
I want to add social and analytics to my game; and Parse seems to be quite nice solution regarding these aspects.
I could only find information about Unity support but I couldn't find anything helpful about how to implement it into Cocos2s-X.
Any info will be much appreciated!

Regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x has a solution for 3rd party service integration, like Facebook, AdMob etc.

The solution is called plugin-x: https://github.com/cocos2d-x/plugin-x

And you could also find some useful solutions in cocos2d-x's wiki page which shows you some help information about how to use plugin-x and how to add your own service into plugin-x.